# How do i parse results from a combine publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to the combine world and have written a query that returns the results I need correctly. It's multi-step, but basically makes an api call over the network, parses the returned json and creates an array of records I need.

```swift
let results2: Publishers.Map<Publishers.ReceiveOn<Publishers.Decode<Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, JSONDecoder.Input>, Wrapper<Question>, JSONDecoder>, DispatchQueue>, [Question]>
```

I'm trying to rewrite a portion of my code and realize that I still don't quite grasp the ins and outs of parsing the results.
If you look at the datatype of results2 you will see the final portion contains an array of `Question`. How do I assign this array to a variable, as in:

```swift
let finalAnswer: [Question] = turnThisIntoAnArray(results2)
```

If possible, I'd prefer a general answer to this general question, rather than providing all the code needed to recreate this specific string of publishers.

thanks

Comment: A Combine publisher doesn't return anything in terms of *return result*. You have to `sink` the pipeline and assign the `receivedValue` to `finalAnswer`. And assign `results2` to a strong reference of `AnyCancellable` type.

Comment: Thanks Vadian! I'm sure that you've answered my question correctly, but I haven't succeeded yet in turning your response into working code. I will continue to look into this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @vadian If you want to write up an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll close it tomorrow with a code example of how I got my array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this working example, notice the variable `results` below:

```swift
  func runQuery() {
     let env = BespokeEnvironment(mainQueue: .main, networkQuery: NetworkQuestionRequestor())
     results = env.networkQuery.reviewedQuestionsQuery(pageCount: 1)
        .sink(
           receiveCompletion: { print($0)},
           receiveValue: { values in
              returnValues.append(contentsOf: values)
           })
     }
```

I originally had:

```
 let results =
   ...
```

And was not getting any records. It turns out the method was completing and returning before the publisher had finished.

In the non-working code, the cancellable was not being saved long enough for the publisher to complete. So I moved `results` into the parent view and made it a `@State` variable. Everything now works correctly.

```swift
   @State var results: AnyCancellable? = nil
```