# In TCA: How to extract from Effect when not in the reducer?

Tags: swift, combine, swift-composable-architecture

I have the results from a publisher in an `Effect<[Int], Error>`
How do I assign that [Int] to a variable?

Although I am able to get the results using this:

```
         case .reviewed:
               return environment.networkQuery.reviewed(pageCount: 1)
                  .catchToEffect()
                  .map(BespokeAction.processQueryResults)
         case let .processQuestionResult(.success(ids)):
             ...
  
         case let .processQuestionResult(.failure(error)):
            print(error)
           ...
```

I want to use the publisher outside of the reducer:

```
let values: Effect<[Question], Error> = environment.networkQuery.reviewed(pageCount: 1)
```

what do I do to `values` to extract the array upon success?

note: this a more finely resolved take on a question I posted previously:

[previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756471/how-do-i-parse-results-from-a-combine-publisher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the code was mostly good, I never saw the results.

This is because the code is inside a function and cancellable was disappearing with the function returning. The publisher immediately stops when the cancellable goes out of scope.

I moved `results` and `returnValues` into the view and now update a `@State` property in the `receiveValue`  closure:

```swift
   @State var returnValues = [Question]()
   @State var results: AnyCancellable? = nil

    ....

   func runQuery() {
     let env = BespokeEnvironment(mainQueue: .main, networkQuery: NetworkQuestionRequestor())
      results = env.networkQuery.reviewedQuestionsQuery(pageCount: 1)
            .sink(
               receiveCompletion: { print($0)},
               receiveValue: { values in
                  returnValues.append(contentsOf: values)
               })
   }
```